# InfluxDB: synchronize timestamps between topics for use in Grafana Geomap

Tags: grafana, influxdb, geomap

I have latitude/longitude values being put into an InfluxDB instance under different topics. They are provided via MQTT, e.g. topics are `foo/bar/lat` and `foo/bar/lon` with the coordinate values as float strings in the message part. These are then processed sequentially by Telegraf.

So each positioning event results in a 2-tuple of entries in different series that have *slightly* different timestamps. The ∆ is typically below 1 millisecond whereas the events are several seconds (or more) apart due to the processing in Telegraf.

When visualizing this in Grafana using a Time Series or (old) Graph panel, the difference does not matter, but the Geomap panel does not recognize the lat/lon values as actual coordinate pairs, so no data are displayed.

How can I write the queries (or a single query?) such that the timestamps are matched? Or can I prevent the timestamps from differing when being processed in Telegraf? There is no actual timestamp in the data sent over MQTT.

Comment: My current workaround is to persist both coordinate values in Node-RED and combine them when the corresponding timestamps are within 1 second. But that is a "Plan B" type of solution.

Comment: As I discovered recently, the very same problem applies to values from different topics (also ingested by Telegraf) that are about to be stacked in Grafana.